# Upon append, change the value and remove the old ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following JSON:

```
[{"page_title":"SaSaZu Club","page_url":"sasazu"},{"page_title":"Karlovy l\u00e1zn?","page_url":"karlovy-lazne"},{"page_title":"James Dean","page_url":"james-dean"},{"page_title":"Club Lavka","page_url":"club-lavka"},{"page_title":"TRETTER'S Cocktail Bar.","page_url":"tretters-cocktail-bar"}]
```

my Ajax which adds TR to the table:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#category").change(function () {
        var category = $('#category option:selected').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/administrator/page/get_page_by_category',
            data: {'category': category},
            async: true, //Hey browser! run the code
            //if we prased data run:
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                var trHTML = '';
                $.each(obj, function (i, item) {
                    trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.page_title + '</td><td>' + item.page_url + '</td></tr>';
                });
                $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Works fine but everytime i use the `$category` and change the value. the new value just goes on top of the exisiting, i would like to display individually each TR there.. i guess i should just use something other then "append?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to overwrite the contents, hence use [`.html(htmlString)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) instead of `.append()`

```
$('#records_table').html(trHTML);
```